# Android Sample CardReader crashes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I finally got to compile the android sample of the cardreader without errors (SDK 4.4.2), but when I run it on my Samsung S4 (Android 4.4.2) it immediately crashes! Does anybody
knows the reason and a solution?
That's the cardreader:

https://developer.android.com/samples/CardReader/index.html

I also got a Nexus 7 and there the app crashes too! Here's the logcat:

```
04-03 23:38:23.280: D/AndroidRuntime(2493): Shutting down VM
04-03 23:38:23.280: W/dalvikvm(2493): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f07ba8)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493): Process: com.example.nfctest, PID: 2493
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nfctest/com.example.nfctest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at com.example.nfctest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     ... 11 more
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.common.logger.LogFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     ... 22 more
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.common.logger.LogFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nfctest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.nfctest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
04-03 23:38:23.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2493):     ... 25 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.common.logger.LogFragment"` Do you have such a class in your project?  If it is as in your link, it has a dependency on the Android Support library, is that included in your build?  Are you dealing with a debug build which skipped proguard, or a release build which went through it?

Comment: thanks now it works but not completely right because when I scan a card it only says ""New tag discovered" and nothing else, what's now the problem?

best regards,
Robert

Comment: Take time to understand the operation of the program and check logcat for anything relevant